# How to make a family of functions which will take as an argument vectors of different classes?

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, vector

As in the question. I want to make one function which will be able to manage different vectors. I thought about using inheritance.

```
class A : public C {public: void do();};
class B : public C {public: void do();};
class C {
public:
virtual void do();
}
```

now my function which should operate on multiple classes, here: A and B

```
void function(vector<C*>* array) {
   for (int i = 0; i < array->size(); i++) {
      array->at(i)->do();
   }
}
```

in my program, I use this function like that:

```
vector<A*>* array = new vector<A*>();
array->push_back(new A());
function(array);
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
The Visual Studio reports that it cannot convert from vector<A*>* to vector<C*>*
```

Comment: So why not template function?

Comment: I read something about templates but I don't know how to do it. I will try using them.

Comment: @FirstStep: He hasn't said not a template function. He said he doesn't know how to solve the problem. The solution may very well be a template function.

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to `new` a `vector`.  You can probably just declare a `vector` and then pass it by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With templates, something like:

```
template<typename T>
void function(vector<T*>* array) {
   for (int i = 0; i < array->size(); i++) {
      array->at(i)->do();
   }
}
```

Note that you didn't need C. You might want to restrict to specific types. This is usually done via `std::enable_if<>`, something like:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, A>::value
                      || std::is_same<T, B>::value, void >::type function(vector<T*>* array) { /...
```

Use `std::is_same<>` if you want to check for exact match, `std::is_base_of<>` if you're okay with inherited types.